# Javascript Object.Create() method

Tags: javascript

If you look in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) it says that `Object.Create()`:

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified
>   prototype object and properties.

I think this is ambiguous, because it doesn't say which `prototype` property is modified (internal `[[Prototype]]` or publicly available `Prototype` all functions have). Should it be fixed in the docs or maybe I'm not aware of the terminology?

Comment: Did you see the examples? I think that's so clear. That you create will be `Object.Create( YourAnotherObject.prototype )`

Comment: it means the prototype of new created object (ie. the return value of this method call) will be set as the given `proto` argument, in code: `var o = Object.create(proto); Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === proto` returns `true`

Comment: I know that it modifies the internal `[[Prototype]]`. I'm only asking whether the docs should be corrected.

Comment: @user4205580 I still can't understand your confusion. Which "`prototype` property" are you referring to? If you're thinking about `Function.prototype`, then that is only relevant to the `new` operator. The `create()` method does not use it and creates objects with "magic".

Comment: @billc.cn functions are objects as well + functions have two `prototype` properties - internal `[[Prototype]]` and accessible `Prototype`. Now if the docs says an object is created, it doesn't say if it's a function object or usual object with only one `prototype` property.

Comment: @user4205580 Ah, I see where your confusion is. I did not expect you're thinking about supplying a function to `create()`. The end result will be the same as supplying any other types: the argument will be set to the `[[prototype]]` internal slot of a newly created object. The result will still be a sub-type of `Object` only (not a `Function`) but will have access to all the "static" properties of the original function object.

Comment: @billc.cn actually it's not about parameters of `create()`. It's about its return value. The docs say it returns an object (but it doesn't say if this object is a function or not), so I can't tell which prototype property is being set (the returned object might be a function anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The wording on MDN may need some improvement, but the ECMAScript 5.1 spec linked at the bottom of that article is very clear.

There's no constructor function or `Function.prototype` involved here. You can supply *any* object as the first argument. The `prototype` of no `Function` will be modified in the process.